# PineScript RSI Conditional Statement not working

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, pine-script, trading

I am trying to change long and short conditions based on RSI values but the below code is not working and the values are not initializing. The error says **enterLong** not found.

**Code:**

```
rs1=rsi(close,14) > 50

rs2=rsi(close,14) < 50

if rs1

    enterLong = cshort  
    enterShort = clong 
if rs2

    enterLong = clong 
    enterShort = cshort
```

Can you help in assigning values based on RSI condition? Everything else is working just fine. If I just use the code with only one set of conditions without using **if rs1** and **if rs2**, the code works just fine but the drawback is that I can't backtest it then and we can use only one set of conditions (e.g only RSI>50 condition)

Comment: Please format your code and add you full code.

Comment: Baris the error is only in this snippet. Rest of the code was working fine but I decided to tweak my strategy a bit and use values based on RSI value.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring variable in the `if`'s local scope, so they disappear once you exit that scope. You don't supply dependencies so it's difficult to figure things out, but given that `cshort` and `clong` are booleans and you are using Pine v4, this may work:

```
rs1=rsi(close,14) > 50
rs2=rsi(close,14) < 50

enterLong = false
enterShort = false
if rs1
    enterLong := cshort  
    enterShort := clong 
if rs2
    enterLong := clong 
    enterShort := cshort
```